# F# type conflict

Tags: f#, paket, f#-compiler-services, fantomas

I am using the parseFile function from [Fantomas.FCS](https://github.com/fsprojects/fantomas) as follows:

```
open FSharp.Compiler.Text
open Fantomas.FCS.Parse
// ... 
let ast, errors = parseFile false (FSharp.Compiler.Text.SourceText.ofString "let mutable x = 3") []
```

However, the compiler says that

`The type 'FSharp.Compiler.Text.ISourceText' is not compatible with the type 'FSharp.Compiler.Text.ISourceText (Fantomas.FCS, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)'`

I have located the file [here](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/Compiler/Facilities/prim-lexing.fsi), which seems to be in the nuget package FSharp.Compiler.Service. However, downloading the latest version of that does not resolve the conflict. I then looked at the version Fantomas.FCS (version 5.0.0-beta-002) is using. It seems that Fantomas is obtaining the `FSharp.Compiler.Text` namespace files from github: https://github.com/fsprojects/fantomas/blob/master/paket.dependencies. I have tried to use paket to download these files, using a similar setup as Fantomas, but had issues with transitive dependencies. The method also seems messy. Is there a way to resolve the type incompatibility?

Comment: I tried your code but couldn't reproduce the issue, this compiles fine for me

Comment: I assume you tried it with the same dependency setups. If not, perhaps the issue got fixed with new versions. Anyway, I ended up using FSharp.Formatting.CodeFormat (https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Formatting/codeformat.html) to tokenize F# code.

Comment: yeah I used version 5.0.0-beta-002 as you stated